# Typetrait to get value type of contiguous-memory containers

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits

I need a typetrait that would return value type for the following "contiguous-memory" types (to which `operator[]` can be applied):

`std::vector<T, Args...>`, `std::array<T, N>`, `T[]`, `T[N]`, and `T*` (with possibly CV qualifiers like `T* const`). The trait should return `T` for all above types.

Is there a more concise implementation in C++17, than the tedious one below? Like somehow gathering all pointer cases in one specialization and appliyng `std::remove_ptr`, same for `T[N]` with `std::remove_extent`.

```
template<class T> struct remove_array_like;
template<class T> struct remove_array_like<T*> { using type = T; };
template<class T> struct remove_array_like<T* const> { using type = T; };
template<class T> struct remove_array_like<T* volatile> { using type = T; };
template<class T> struct remove_array_like<T* const volatile> { using type = T; };

template<class T> struct remove_array_like<T[]> { using type = T; };
template<class T, std::size_t N> 
struct remove_array_like<T[N]> { using type = T; };

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct remove_array_like<std::array<T, N>> { using type = T; };

template<class T, class... Args>
struct remove_array_like<std::vector<T, Args...>> { using type = T; };
```

Comment: I think there is nothing like collective to the above and (IMO) nothing wrong with having like you did .....

Comment: This implementation doesn't work with user defined contiguous containers. It's also missing `std::basic_string` which is a contiguous container. Also, since you want to support `T*`, then why not also `std::span` (and correspondingly `std::string_view`)? How about contiguous range view adapters?

Comment: @eerorika I agree, however for my particular purposes it is suffice to support types that I mentioned. Though max66 apparently gave an awesome generic solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need a typetrait that would return value type for the following "contiguous-memory" types (to which operator[] can be applied):

To "extract" the required type, it seems to me that you can simply use the `operator[]` itself, removing references, volatiles and consts. See the following helper struct

```
template <typename T>
struct contained_type
 { using type = std::remove_cv_t<
                   std::remove_reference_t<
                      decltype(std::declval<T>()[0])>>; };
```

You can write your `contained_type` struct using SFINAE, so with an additional defaulted template parameter

```
template <typename, typename = void>
struct remove_array_like;
```

It seems to me that you needs only three specializations.

One for contigous-memory containers (so for containers with a `data()` method that return a pointer to the start of the contigous contained memory), that is for `std::vector`, `std::array`,  `std::string` and other strings types

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_array_like<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().data())>>
   : public contained_type<T>
 { };
```

one for pointers

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_array_like<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<T>>>
   : public contained_type<T>
 { };
```

and one for arrays

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_array_like<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_array_v<T>>>
   : public contained_type<T>
 { };
```

The following is a full compiling C++17 example

```
#include <set>
#include <array>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct contained_type
 { using type = std::remove_cv_t<
                   std::remove_reference_t<
                      decltype(std::declval<T>()[0])>>; };

template <typename, typename = void>
struct remove_array_like;

template <typename T>
struct remove_array_like<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().data())>>
   : public contained_type<T>
 { };

template <typename T>
struct remove_array_like<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<T>>>
   : public contained_type<T>
 { };

template <typename T>
struct remove_array_like<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_array_v<T>>>
   : public contained_type<T>
 { };

int main ()
 {
   using T1 = remove_array_like<std::vector<int>>::type;
   //using T2 = remove_array_like<std::deque<int>>::type; // error! no data(), no contigous
   using T3 = remove_array_like<std::array<int, 1u>>::type;
   using T4 = remove_array_like<std::string>::type;
   using T5 = remove_array_like<int * volatile>::type;
   using T6 = remove_array_like<int const [1u]>::type;
   using T7 = remove_array_like<int volatile []>::type;
   // using T8 = remove_array_like<std::set<int>>::type; // error!
   // using T9 = remove_array_like<int>::type; // error!

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<T1, int> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<T3, int> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<T4, char> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<T5, int> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<T6, int> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<T7, int> );
 }
```

Starting from C++20 you can use `std::remove_cvref`, so `contained_type` can be simplified as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct contained_type
 { using type = std::remove_cvref_t<
                   decltype(std::declval<T>()[0])>; };
```

Comment: @xskxzr - And also more semantically correct. I suppose I was sleeping when I've used `std::conditional_t`. Thanks.